# Date format for php prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have set dob as type "date" in my html and in my stu table i am taking it as a string so i have made it as varchar, but null is getting stored as default value

Check the code...

```
 /* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `stu` (`name`, `gender` , `dob`) VALUES (
?, ?, ? ) "))) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */

if (!$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name , $gender , $dob )) {
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the $dob variable contains the desired value? Perhaps echo it before the mysqli statements to check.

Comment: Show how you are defining `$dob`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is OK (though we can't see if you actually `execute()` the query). The problem is the code that we can't see, where you define `$dob`.

When you pass `$dob` to `bind_param()` it should be a string, not an object or anything else that you might have. Format `$dob` as a string and that will enable it to be inserted into the table.

I also suggest changing your field to a `DATE` instead of a `VARCHAR`. Your varchar field will accept any string date format but a `DATE` field will need `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: My fault bro... there was problem in definiton